# SetDropTarget not working if Jar ran as Administrator

Tags: java

I'm making a drag n drop function with my JLabel, it runs normally if I run it with normal privilege. But now I have to do something with a file being dragged with Admin privilege, but my program won't allow me to drag anyfile if I run it as Admin. How do I get this to work? Thanks :)

**Edit**

Here's my screenshot:
[image]

Left one is when I run the Jar from CMD with normal privilege (just cmd),
Right one is when I run the Jar from CMD with Admin Privilege (right click and Run as Admin).

The reason that my program need admin privilege is that because it is accessing a part of registry which can only be manipulated with admin privilege.

Comment: What do you mean by Admin privilege? If working before and not now then what changes have you made? Sorry with information no one can help you

Comment: Please post some of your code here.won't allow means what problem it have??what does that mean?

Comment: @Jatin: Question updated :D

Comment: @VigneshVino: Question updated :D